# How to load a static file in django v4.0.5?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I was trying to load a static file i.e my CSS in django and i am doing evrything taught in tutorial but it isn't happening. i have my CSS inside static folder.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main.css' %}">
    <title> Django </title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
    <div>
        <nav id="a1">
            <a href="{% url 'home'%}" class="a">Home</a>
            <a href="{% url 'about'%}" class="a">About</a>
            <a href="{% url 'contact'%}" class="a">Contact</a>
            <a href="{% url 'courses'%}" class="a">Courses</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </header>
```

Here, is my settings.py file as i was following tutorial,
settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIR=[
    BASE_DIR,"static"
]
```

Comment: how do you know that file is not loaded? Check devtools (F12) -> network if the file was loaded (or attempted to be loaded and failed)

Comment: BTW, I think it should be `STATICFILES_DIRS` i.o. `STATICFILES_DIR`

Comment: `BASE_DIR,"static"` there is no comma in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files) it's slash. "static" folder under BASE_DIR. You have array of two misleading items, config is broken.

Answer (score 0):

IN `settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

IN `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {"document_root":settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
]
```

If your `DEBUG` is `False` then you need to run `python manage.py collectstatic`